# Overloading operators for a custom cupy data type

Tags: cupy

I want to create new data types in cupy. I'm thinking of a "fixed point" decimal type, and multivectors from geometric algebra. I understand how to create a new data type, this is well documented. But how do I overload implementations of +, *, and @ or create extra implementations of other functions?